# Exclusive selecting list elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have myself an unordered list:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-class="{ 'active': selected }" ng-click="selected = !selcted">Stuff 1</li>
    <li ng-class="{ 'active': selected }" ng-click="selected = !selcted">Stuff 2</li>
    <li ng-class="{ 'active': selected }" ng-click="selected = !selcted">Stuff 3</li>
</ul>
```

I want to apply a class to a list item a user selects. Only one item can have that class at a time. What's the best angular-ish way to approach this? There are about a dozen elements or so, so I'd rather not declare a new variable for each item.

Comment: I'd love if people would explain their downvotes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a property for each item:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-class="{ 'active': selected == 1 }" ng-click="selected = 1">Stuff 1</li>
    <li ng-class="{ 'active': selected == 2 }" ng-click="selected = 2">Stuff 2</li>
    <li ng-class="{ 'active': selected == 3 }" ng-click="selected = 3">Stuff 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want angular-ish  use ng-repat

HTML

```
<ul ng-repeat="s in stuffs">
    <li ng-class="{active:$index==selected}" ng-click="selected=$index">{{s}}</li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$scope.stuffs = ['Stuff 1', 'Stuff 2', 'Stuff 3'];
```